# PHPUnit Single bracket line uncovered

Tags: phpunit

can anyone tell me why this one line after the last break; stays uncovered and therefore the method get a coverage fo 0%!

```
private function isADateParameter($fieldName, $fieldValue){
    if(!is_array($fieldValue)){
        $this->addPayloadError('filter',320, $fieldName. 'is a date field and needs an array filter like {"gt":"2015-05-01"}');
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($fieldValue as $criteria => $date){
        $ar_date = explode('-', $date);
        switch(false){
            case in_array($criteria, ['gt', 'lt', 'gte', 'lte']):
                $this->addPayloadError('filter',321, $fieldName. ' supports only constraints gt, lt, gte or lte');
                break;
            case preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date):
                $this->addPayloadError('filter',322, $fieldName. ' supports only date in format YYYY-MM-DD');
                break;
            case checkdate($ar_date[1], $ar_date[2], $ar_date[0]):
                $this->addPayloadError('filter',323, $date. ' is not a real date');
                break;
        } //uncovered red line in html report
    }
    if(isset($this->payloadErrors['filter']) && count($this->payloadErrors['filter']) > 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this bug report](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=969), specifially the close note:

> This is not a bug. In theory "$value" could be something else than 1, 2 or 3 and in that case the switch() would *not* leave due to one of the values. Xdebug can not make assumptions on what "doSomething()" returns an has no way to know that all that ever is returned than 1, 2 or 3. The last } of each function and method includes an implicit "return NULL;" - which PHP sees as executable code. Because there is a possible code path where the } is not hit, it is marked as "not executed".

In your case, you have three case statements, that I imagine you've written tests for, but there's a third, implied path that you may or may not be testing for - what to do if none of the three cases match?

**tl;dr:** Add a `default` case to the switch, and make sure your tests exercise it. Or don't and ignore that coverage line.

Comment: Hmm but I simply can't add a default case, it would make no sense in my module. And yes, I have tests which executes every given case. If none of the cases match, then I have the last "return true", which says I have no errors. And for this case I have tests, too. I have tests for every return line and vor every case inside the switch.

Comment: Furthermore, Xdebug should not make any assumptions of what could be or not. The code is beeing executed, every other line excerpt this one is marked green.